Error utf-8 enconding - Lib python FtpLib
I am having trouble listing files from an FTP server using Python's ftplib. The server appears to send data that is causing a UTF-8 decoding error. Here’s a summary of the problem and what I’ve tried:
Code
from ftplib import FTP

try:
    
    ftp = FTP('ftp')
    ftp.login(user='user', passwd='psw')
    
    
    ftp.encoding = 'utf-8'
    
    
    arquivos = ftp.nlst()
    print(f'Arquivos: {arquivos}')
    
except Exception as Err:
    print(f'Erro na conexão: {Err}')
finally:
    if 'ftp' in locals():
        ftp.quit()

The error:
Error in connection: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 17: invalid continuation byte
Additional Information
The server does not support UTF-8, as indicated by FileZilla with the message: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
I also tried using latin-1 encoding, but it returns the same error
